# have section fade in with anchor in URL?

Tags: jquery, hash

I have a site (can be seen here: http://www.stevenacres.com/meggriffiths/ ) that I'm working on. It's a very small site, so I'm currently using hidden divs for navigation. The only problem is you can't link to a specific page. I'm trying to get the location.hash to work but I can't seem to get it to work. Basically everything is in an id'd div, such as #cv, #contact, and #portfolios, and I want jQuery to check the URL for the anchor/hash tag at the end first. If there is a hashtag, it should fade out the #frontpage div, and fadeIn() whatever tag is in the URL. Can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a great plugin that takes away all the "hardships" off working with hashtags.

[jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)

I've used it one of my websites, and it also handles the scenario put forth in your question.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. The only problem is that there is hardly any documentation at all. Just jumping right in, it's completely over my head. :(

Comment: I ended up going with jQuery BBQ... much better documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). It's got great documentation and is browser-history (back/forward) compatible and allows for hash tag recognition.